# What is the Go equivalent to assert() in C++?

Tags: go

I'm looking for a condition check in Go which can terminate the program execution like [assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) in C++.

Comment: There's not one. Try `if condition { panic(message) }`.

Comment: See also https://golang.org/doc/faq#assertions

Comment: If you need it did testing there’s excellent `testing `package   Also have a look at https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert

Comment: I understand that it is a design choice to not support assert() in Go. I asked this question just because I wanted to use it in a course project for debugging purpose, not in production.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky  assert of testing package requires a test T parameter to be used, that function in the application doesn't have or provide, as they aren't test themselves, but the main code.

Comment: I use a combination of two things: a custom function and build tags with disabling assertions doing release build via `go build -tags release` (where my function just checks if it is tagged as a release or not).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As mentioned by commenters, [Go does not have assertions](https://golang.org/doc/faq#assertions).

A comparable alternative in Go is the [built-in function `panic(...)`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics), gated by a condition:

```
if condition {
  panic(err)
}
```

This [article titled "Defer, Panic, and Recover"](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) may also be informative.

Comment: Don't use panics, but properly handle the error! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356602/golang-panic-crash-prevention

Comment: sry @RickyA, but this ignores the stark difference between regular runtime errors and programming/logic bugs: `panic()` in Go (as `assert` in C et al.) is used to signal when a bug has been encountered; you check for invariants that must never be violated (because the code should properly handle error conditions...), but if the invariant is broken, a Bug has occurred. Examples are like "index must be within bounds" when accessing a slice, etc.

Comment: I guess the next question is, does an invariant having be violated warrant the program having to halt execution? E.g. imagine the condition being triggered only by some work items in a queue, even if an "invariant" has been violated, I still want to process the next item?

Comment: @MrR That very much depends on the error. A bad message coming from the message queue in most cases will be skipped with a mere log entry and sent to the DLQ. Repeatedly failing to connect to the main database in most cases will warrant a `panic` (or its unrecoverable cousin - `log.Fatal()`).

Comment: So it's eventually possible to create a function implementing that __missing core feature (again)__ in Go. `func assert(condition bool) {if <condition> == false { log.Errorf(...); panic() }}`. But it will be more useful if Golang team accepts to implement it in Go 1.58, in year 2038, or later.

Answer (score 5):

I actually use a little helper:

```
func failIf(err error, msg string) {
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error " + msg + ": %v", err)
  }
}
```

And then in use:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "my_user@/my_database")
defer db.Close()
failIf(err, "connecting to my_database")
```

On failure it generates:

> error connecting to my_database: <error from MySQL/database>

Answer (score 0):

I use this generic Go function in tests:

```
func assertEqual[T comparable](t *testing.T, expected T, actual T) {
    t.Helper()
    if expected == actual {
        return
    }
    t.Errorf("expected (%+v) is not equal to actual (%+v)", expected, actual)
}

func assertSliceEqual[T comparable](t *testing.T, expected []T, actual []T) {
    t.Helper()
    if len(expected) != len(actual) {
        t.Errorf("expected (%+v) is not equal to actual (%+v): len(expected)=%d len(actual)=%d",
            expected, actual, len(expected), len(actual))
    }
    for i := range expected {
        if expected[i] != actual[i] {
            t.Errorf("expected[%d] (%+v) is not equal to actual[%d] (%+v)",
                i, expected[i],
                i, actual[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Some people use [testify](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify) but I prefer to copy+paste above function.